# LLVM and GCC toolchain selection

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-cpp

I am using the [LLVM toolchain for Bazel](https://github.com/bazel-contrib/toolchains_llvm) (with Bazel 7.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04) this way:

*MODULE.bazel*:

```
module(name = "gcc_llvm_test")

bazel_dep(name = "toolchains_llvm", version = "0.10.3")
git_override(
    module_name = "toolchains_llvm",
    commit = "bba94f8138ab454d70afcd263788b34e2801e2ba",
    remote = "https://github.com/bazel-contrib/toolchains_llvm.git",
)

bazel_dep(name = "rules_foreign_cc", version = "0.10.1")

llvm = use_extension("@toolchains_llvm//toolchain/extensions:llvm.bzl", "llvm")
llvm.toolchain(
   llvm_version = "16.0.0",
)

use_repo(llvm, "llvm_toolchain")

register_toolchains("@llvm_toolchain//:all")
```

*BUILD.bazel*:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello_world",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
)
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string ver_string(int a, int b, int c) {
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << a << '.' << b << '.' << c;
  return ss.str();
}

std::string true_cxx =
#ifdef __clang__
   "clang++";
#else
   "g++";
#endif

  std::string true_cxx_ver =
#ifdef __clang__
    ver_string(__clang_major__, __clang_minor__, __clang_patchlevel__);
#else
    ver_string(__GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__, __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__);
#endif

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "true_cxx: " << true_cxx << std::endl;
    std::cout << "true_cxx_ver: " << true_cxx_ver << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `bazel run //:hello_world` I get the following output

```
Hello, World!
true_cxx: clang++
true_cxx_ver: 16.0.0
```

If I uncomment the line `register_toolchains("@llvm_toolchain//:all")` I get:

```
Hello, World!
true_cxx: g++
true_cxx_ver: 11.4.0
```

This makes perfect sense. How can I switch between both toolchains without having to comment the toolchain out? I think the desired solution would be a Bazel config placed in `.bazelrc`, e.g.

```
build:gcc --some_flags
build:clang16 --some_other_flags
```

In an earlier version of these toolchain rules and Bazel 6.0 I had this config:

```
build:clang14 --incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution
```

Running with `--incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution` selected LLVM/CLang compiler for me and without it, I had good old GCC. In Bazel 7.0.0 the flag is set by default. I am a bit unsure what now is the proper way to select a C++ toolchain. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a narrow sense, `--noincompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution` will get you the pre-Bazel 7.0.0 default behavior, which sounds like you have configured to use GCC.

If you want something that will continue working after the flag is removed (see [bazel#7260](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7260) for the current status), you'll need to [migrate to platforms](https://bazel.build/concepts/platforms). How to do that depends on which GCC toolchain you're using. Generally you need to:

1. Ensure there's a [constraint](https://bazel.build/extending/platforms#constraints-platforms) which each of your toolchains is [target_compatible_with](https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#common.target_compatible_with) different values of
2. Create platforms that are compatible with each of your toolchains using that constraint
3. [Specify the platform](https://bazel.build/extending/platforms#specifying-build-platform) to build using the `--platforms` flag

Comment: I am using the the pre-existing default C++ toolchain (since I am on Ubuntu 22.04 this is GCC 11.4.0). Is `bazel build --platforms=@local_config_platform//:host` the right command to use the "default" toolchain?

Comment: That's `@local_config_cc`, which comes from [cc_configure.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl). There isn't a lot of room to configure that one. You could copy the relevant starlark code to modify it though. https://github.com/f0rmiga/gcc-toolchain also looks interesting.